# How to choose a Clojure JSON library

Tags: json, clojure

There are multiple JSON parser/writer libraries available for Clojure, including:

- [clojure/data.json](https://github.com/clojure/data.json)
- [cheshire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire)
- [clj-json](https://github.com/mmcgrana/clj-json/)

What are the pros and cons of each, especially regarding speed, memory footprint, and programming convenience? Are there any other important factors to consider?

Comment: from cheshire (what I use) docs: clojure-json had really nice features (custom encoders), but was slow; clj-json had no features, but was fast. Cheshire encodes JSON fast, with added support for more types and the ability to use custom encoders.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I decided to run a [little shootout](https://gist.github.com/8783558) (the link is to results and the code used to test).

In terms of speed, `clj-json` is the fastest, 1.7x `cheshire`, and 5.6x `clojure.data.json` for a simple parse/generate task.

`clojure.data.json` has the smallest footprint, and `clj-json` and `cheshire` follow. `cheshire` has some superb features, though, and is my preferred library for dealing with JSON. You get support for SMILE, as well as a lovely interface for interpreting JSON (adding types, special rules on keys, etc) and custom encoders (the last also found in `clojure.data.json`).

Comment: How about jsonista?